# Case with multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
id No_trans Bank
1   2       VISA
1   1       PAYPAL
2   3       MASTERCARD
3   1       MASTERCARD
3   4       PAYPAL
4   1       PAYPAL
```

What I need to do is if `id` has `PAYPAL`, change it to another bank, for example.
For `id` = 1, `PAYPAL` should be as `VISA`, but for `id` = 3, it  should be `MASTERCARD`, however, for `id` = 4, it should be `PAYPAL`  because it doesn't have another `Bank` record.

```
select id ,count(No_trans) , 
 case Bank when  PAYPAL then VISA 
 when PAYPAL then MASTERCARD 
 else 
  PAYPAL
 end as bank
from table
```

Grouping by 1 and 3
is not going to work, because I need to change it depending on which other record has the same `id`  bank.

If this ID has a bank different from `PAYPAL`, use it for other records with the same ID, if not, use it as it is.

```
create temporary table t1
(
    ID INT
    , no_trans int
    , bank  varchar (255)

  );

 INSERT INTO t1 values
  (1,   2 ,      'VISA'),
(1 ,  1     ,  'PAYPAL'),
(2,   3     , 'MASTERCARD'),
(3 ,  1      , 'MASTERCARD'),
(3,   4      , 'PAYPAL'),
(4 ,  1      , 'PAYPAL');


select * from t1 
where id = 1
```

return

```
 '1','2','VISA'
'1','1','PAYPAL'
```

I need

```
 '1','2','VISA'
'1','1','VISA'
```

for

select * from t1 
where id = 3 
should be

```
ID, no_trans, bank
3, 1, MASTERCARD
3, 4, MASTERCARD
```

for

select * from t1 
where id = 4

```
ID, no_trans, bank
4, 1, PAYPAL
```

Comment: combination can be only as visa, mastercard , paypal , or visa and paypal or mastercard and paypal, one id hav have many records but as bank only . visa or paypal, or mastercard or paypal, it cannot . be visa and master card under same id

Comment: Can you please produce a table of desired output? That would help tremendously.
This is going to be difficult and not reliable with the current data that you have.

Comment: @David Buttrick done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id,
       coalesce(max(case when Bank <> 'PayPal' then Bank end),
                max(Bank)
               )
from t
group by id;
```

If you want the original rows, then perhaps a subquery is simpler:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.bank
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id 
        order by (t2.bank <> 'PayPal) desc
        limit 1
       ) as new_bank
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select 
  ID, 
  no_trans, 
  If (id = 1 and bank = 'PAYPAL', 'VISA',bank)as bank 
from t1 
where id = 1
```

For Id = 3

```
select 
  ID, 
  no_trans, 
  If (id = 3 and bank = 'PAYPAL', 'MATERCARD',bank) as bank 
from t1 
where id = 3;
```

If you need all of them combined:

```
select 
  ID, 
  no_trans, 
  If (bank = 'PAYPAL',If(id = 1,'VISA',If(id=3,'MASTERCARD',bank)),bank) as bank 
from t1;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc013/10/0)